# PHP-FPM doesn't process php request

Tags: php, lighttpd

I have a strange situation, I have installed lighttpd and php5-fpm through aptitude

I've created one vhost and the and the fpm pool.

This is the main.conf (global FPM)

```
[global]

        pid = /var/run/php-fpm.pid

        error_log = /home/lighttpd/log/php-fpm.log

        log_level = error

        emergency_restart_threshold = 5

        emergency_restart_interval = 2

        process_control_timeout = 2

        daemonize = yes

        include=/home/lighttpd/vhosts/*/conf/php-fpm.conf
```

This is the vhost's pool

```
[website.com]
    listen                 = 127.0.0.1:9000
    listen.backlog         = -1

    user  = website.com
    group = website.com

    pm                   = dynamic
    pm.max_requests      = 0
    pm.max_children      = 2
    pm.start_servers     = 1
    pm.min_spare_servers = 1
    pm.max_spare_servers = 1


    request_terminate_timeout = 2
    request_slowlog_timeout   = 1
    slowlog                   = /home/lighttpd/vhosts/website.com/log/php-slow.log

    chroot = /home/lighttpd/vhosts/website.com/web
    ; Chdir to this directory at the start. This value must be an absolute path.
    ; Default Value: current directory or / when chroot
    ;chdir = /

    catch_workers_output = yes


    env[HOSTNAME] = $HOSTNAME
    env[PATH] = /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin
    env[TMP] = /tmp
    env[TMPDIR] = /tmp
    env[TEMP] = /tmp
```

My lighttpd configuration is:

```
## Moduli da caricare
server.modules                 = (
    "mod_alias",
    "mod_compress",
    "mod_rewrite",
    "mod_redirect",
    "mod_accesslog"
)

## Document root
server.document-root           = "/home/lighttpd/vhosts/"

## File temporanei.
server.upload-dirs             = ("/home/lighttpd/tmp")

## LOG
server.errorlog                = "/home/lighttpd/log/error.log"
accesslog.filename             = "/home/lighttpd/log/access.log"


## File ricercati quando viene richiesta una directory
index-file.names               = (
    "index.php",
    "index.html",
    "index.htm",
    "default.htm"
)


## Negare l'accesso al codice sorgente di questi file
static-file.exclude-extensions = (
    ".php",
    ".pl",
    ".fcgi",
    ".conf"
)

server.pid-file                = "/var/run/lighttpd.pid"

dir-listing.encoding           = "utf-8"
server.dir-listing             = "disable"

server.username                = "lighttpd"
server.groupname               = "lighttpd"


## Compressione dei contenuti
compress.cache-dir             = "/home/lighttpd/cache/"
compress.filetype              = (
    "text/plain",
    "text/html",
    "application/x-javascript",
    "text/css"
)

## Mapping dei mimetype
include_shell "/usr/share/lighttpd/create-mime.assign.pl"
include_shell "/usr/share/lighttpd/include-conf-enabled.pl"

#Virtual Hosts
include "/home/lighttpd/vhosts/vhosts.conf"
```

and the vhost is:

```
## WEBSITE.COM
$HTTP["host"] =~ "(^|.)website\.com$" {
    server.document-root = "/home/lighttpd/vhosts/website.com/web"
    server.errorlog      = "/home/lighttpd/vhosts/website.com/log/error.log"
    accesslog.filename   = "/home/lighttpd/vhosts/website.com/log/access.log"


    fastcgi.server = ( ".php" =>
                          ( "localhost" =>
                            (
                              "host" => "127.0.0.1",
                              "port" => "9000"
                            )
                          )
)


}
```

If I visit *www.website.com/page.html* it works good.

If I visit *www.website.com/page.php* I always get **404 error**.

I really don't know how to fix it. I also check the process list, and all the processes started well:

```
lighttpd   974  0.0  0.0  88812  2136 ?        S    02:13   0:00 /usr/sbin/lighttpd -f /etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf
root       998  0.0  0.1 127268  4316 ?        Ss   02:13   0:00 /usr/sbin/php5-fpm --fpm-config /etc/php5/fpm/main.conf
1004       999  0.0  0.1 127812  4628 ?        S    02:13   0:00 /usr/sbin/php5-fpm --fpm-config /etc/php5/fpm/main.conf
```

also **netstat -lnp** confirm it:

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9000          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      998/php5-fpm
```

Could someone help me? I dont' understand why PHP pages are not processed... I also checked the .log and I don't see errors.

### Update

I tried `chroot /home/lighttpd/vhosts/website.com/` and then `chdir /web` (for the http docs) but nothing. I have php-fpm.conf (the pool) at `/home/lighttpd/vhosts/website.com/conf/php-fpm.conf`.

Answer (score 0):

Try getting rid of the `chroot` in the pool config, I think the webserver is passing the full file path to the FastCGI server and (of course) it won't be able to find the file.